# SyntaxError: Unexpected token Node js tutorial

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I am doing this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4 and when I when i try to start server I get this error

```
/server.js:84
 .put(function(req, res) {
 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

and this is how my code looks like

```
// server.js

  var router = express.Router();              // get an instance of the express Router
  // middleware to use for all requests
  router.use(function(req, res, next){
      // do logging
      console.log('For every request this message is being shown.');
      next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
  });

  // test route to make sure everything is working
  router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.json({ message: 'Whatsup Welcome to my first node api!'});
  });

  // more routes for our API will continue here
  // on routes that end in /Bears
  router.route('/bears')

    // create a bear (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/bears)
    .post(function(req, res) {

        var bear = new Bear();      // create a new instance of the Bear model
        bear.name = req.body.name;  // set the bears name (comes from the request)

        bear.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Bear has been born!' });
        });


    })

    // get all the bears (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api/bears)
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Bear.find(function(err, bears) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(bears);
        });
    });
  // on routes that end in /bears/:bear_id
  // ------------------------------------------------
  router.route('/bears/:bear_id')
  // get all the bears (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api/bears/:bear_id)
"line :84 ->>>" .get(function(req, res) {
        Bear.find(function(err, bears) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(bears);
        });
    });

  // update the bear with this id (accessed at PUT http://localhost:8080/api/bears/:bear_id)
 .put(function(req, res) {
      // use our bear model to find the bear we want
      Bear.findById(req.params.bear_id, function(err, bear) {

          if (err)
              res.send(err);

          bear.name = req.body.name;  // update the bears info

          // save the bear
          bear.save(function(err) {
              if (err)
                  res.send(err); }

              res.json({ message: 'Bear updated!' });
          });

      });
  });

  // REGISTER OUR ROUTES here
  // all of our routes will be prefixed with /api
  app.use('/api', router);

  // START THE server

  app.listen(port);
  console.log('Magic is happening on port:' + port);
```

Comment: Whatever you are using to edit your code should support some sort of built in "linting" (validating your syntax) that will highlight these sorts of easy-to-make mistakes for you.

You can even use free online tools like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), [CodePen](http://codepen.io) and the like to put your JS in, "tidy" it to be consistently formatted and readable, and highlight any errors for you. Here is [your code in a CodePen](http://codepen.io/greglockwood/pen/yNrqYO?editors=001) that shows you a small error icon in the bottom right that you can click on to see the offending line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line marked as 84 is not where the error is. It's in the next function you call after that block:

```
// on routes that end in /bears/:bear_id
  // ------------------------------------------------
  router.route('/bears/:bear_id')
  // get all the bears (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api/bears/:bear_id)
"line :84 ->>>" .get(function(req, res) {
        Bear.find(function(err, bears) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(bears);
        });
    });
```

You just finished this `get()` call with a semicolon, but you then go on to call the next function on an expected object:

```
  // update the bear with this id (accessed at PUT http://localhost:8080/api/bears/:bear_id)
 .put(function(req, res) {
      // use our bear model to find the bear we want
      Bear.findById(req.params.bear_id, function(err, bear) {

          if (err)
              res.send(err);

          bear.name = req.body.name;  // update the bears info

          // save the bear
          bear.save(function(err) {
              if (err)
                  res.send(err); }



  res.json({ message: 'Bear updated!' });
      });

  });
});
```

If you remove the semicolon just before the `.put(function(req, res){` line, it should not have a syntax error.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing the `"line : 84 ->>>" ` string isn't meant to be there, either. It will end up trying to call `.get()` on a string, which most likely won't work (but it can't know that until runtime).

Comment: You're right, GregL - I assumed the OP had just put it in there to mark in the source where the line number was.

Comment: @AaronD i have just checked it out and Yes thanks a lot that was the fix.